# regexp_replace() vs. replace() to replace all matches in a string

Tags: postgresql, pattern-matching, replace

By default, in PostgreSQL, [`regexp_replace()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html) replaces the *first* occurrence of a substring in a string, while `replace()` replaces *all* occurrences of a substring in a string. Why is the default behavior different?

(I know that with `regexp_replace` one can use the `g` option to replace all occurrences of a substring in a string.)

Examples:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('hello world', 'o', 'z');  -- returns "hellz world"
SELECT regexp_replace('hello world', 'o', 'z', 'g'); -- returns "hellz wzrld"
SELECT replace('hello world', 'o', 'z'); -- returns: "hellz wzrld"
```

Comment: If the default of `regexp_replace` is same as `replace`,  `replace` is not needed.  Additionally,  `g` option is the same behavior of Unix tools that operate regular expressions such as `sed`.

Comment: I took the liberty to fix the twisted bit about `replace()` in question. Now it should make sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Why?

Because Postgres [`replace()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) is a standard SQL function that works the same as in other RDBMS. Example: [`replace()` in SQL Server:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/ms186862%28v=sql.120%29.aspx)

> Replaces all occurrences of a specified string value with another string value.

While [`regexp_replace()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) is used to ...

> Replace substring(s) matching a POSIX regular expression.

The handling of [regular expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) is obviously guided by the POSIX standard and works the same as other tools implementing it. [The manual:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER)

> POSIX regular expressions provide a more powerful means for pattern
>   matching than the `LIKE` and `SIMILAR TO` operators. Many Unix tools such
>   as `egrep`, `sed`, or `awk` use a pattern matching language that is similar
>   to the one described here.